# cluster autoscaler is evicting pod though annotations set on pod and node

Tags: jenkins, amazon-eks, autoscaling, kubernetes-statefulset

Deployed cluster autoscaler (CA) on EKS cluster. Despite of adding required annotations, CA is rescheduling pod on another node.

EKS cluster- `1.19`  .
CA version:- `1.19.4`
workload:- `jenkins statefulset`
annotation added-

```
 cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict: "false"
```

above annotation is added at statefulset as well as pod level.

node annotation:-

```
cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled=true
```

Same annotations are added for CA pod as well as underlying node.
Still it is not working as expected. Anyone has any idea, what I missed here ?

Comment: can you explain what is the current and expected behaviour?

Comment: it should not evict the pod which has annotations